# How to remove part of a url in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-5, mandrill

I am using a mandrill template to send emails and I need to remove part of the url.
Currently the url is https://www.something_extra.something.com . I just want it to be https://www.something.com

The code is as follows :

```
async: true,
      vars: {
        'name' => product_editor&.name,
        'solution_name' => "<a href=#{product_url(product)}>#{product.name}</a>",
      },
```

So here  `product_url(product)` has the url in the form https://www.something_extra.something.com . I need to make it in the form https://www.something.com

Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
async: true,
      vars: {
        'name' => product_editor&.name,
        'solution_name' => "<a href=#{product_url(product).sub(/\A(https?:\/\/www)\.\w+(\.something\.com)\b/, '\1\2')}>#{product.name}</a>",
      },
```